# Cassandra: Controlling which node receives data

Tags: cassandra, partitioning, sharding

My understanding of Cassandra's recommended clustering approach is to ensure that each node in the cluster receives an equal distribution of data, by hashing a document's unique Id. My question is if there is a way to change this and define a custom key for "intelligently" routing a document to a specific node in the cluster?

In my scenario, I have data which relates to a specific entity (think client-project-task-item) Across all my data; I will have enough items to require some horizontal scaling; however, each search will always relate to a given client-project-task for which the data set is only a moderate size.

Is there a way to create this type of partitioning / routing (different names I've seen for the same thing) logic in Cassandra?

Thanks; Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clustering approach in Cassandra is not just for an equal distribution of data. It also ensures that all read/write operations are distributed across the cluster to make these operations faster. In addition to this, most likely you will have replication factor greater than 1 to ensure data redundancy so that a node failure does not result in the data loss.

Back to your question and to your own answer. If you use the same partition key for the data, this guarantees that Cassandra partitioning will store the primary replica of the data on the same node, and even more, it will store them in the same partition, ("wide row" in an old way of naming).

Answer (score 0):

I think - http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/share/glossary/gloss_partition_key.html - is the answer I'm looking for

The first column declared in the PRIMARY KEY definition, or in the case of a compound key, multiple columns can declare those columns that form the primary key.